# Monitoring the Java micro services using GRPC calls

Tags: java, kotlin, grpc

We have different services written in Java and kotlin. Service1 calls service2 using GRPC. But Service1 uses another Custom Java client SDK to call the GRPC on service2. So these two Service2 and custom Java client SDK are the actual GRPC components. This client SDK is being used just any other Java library. So the call happens as Service1 call -> client SDK method -> uses GRPC call -> Service2 method.

While doing a load testing we observed that some calls were timing out. Service1 will wait for 7 seconds to get a response from Service2 and if it does not get the response it will timeout. Our observation is that the Service2 is getting the request from Service1 (from the client SDK) only after that 7 seconds and it’s responding on time but by the time response is reached by the Service1 it’s already timed out . I am trying to understand how I can debug or trace if there is a problem with Client SDK or is there a problem with Service1.

I am new to GRPC, Kotlin so any pointers on where I can start?

Comment: Your statement "...Service2 is getting the request from Service1 (from the client SDK) only after that 7 seconds .." is not clear. Are you saying Service 2 is receiving the request 7 seconds *after* it was sent by Service 1?

Comment: @SanP yes, the request to service2 is coming exactly after 7 seconds.

Comment: That 7 seconds seems to match the deadline you have set for Service1->Service2 call which is weird. Can you include your code snippets on the client side to start with?